# disable data-val-number in @html.DropdownListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

HOw can i disable data-val-number so i can get value from data-val-required ??

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryId must be a number." data-val-required="This field is required" id="cboCategory" class="input-validation-error"><option>-- Select Category--</option><option value="2">Admin</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a string property instead of an integer:

```
public string CategoryId { get; set; }
```

But that's probably not something you want to be doing. If the category id is an integer then it would make more sense to use a nullable integer and ensure that the value that gets sent to the server is indeed an integer. This can happen my looking at the `value` attribute of the `<option>` elements of this dropdown and ensuring they are integer numbers.